# How to modify the list of applications launched by kdeinit5?

Tags: kde, startup

Each time my machine boot, few applications are started by `kdeinit5`, in particular `konqueror` and a mouse utility program.

I could not find where this list of applications is specified, to remove the unwanted ones.

How to remove applications from the list of programs started by `kdeinit5`?

Context:

- Debian with KDE plasma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GUI: System Settings → Startup and Shutdown → Autostart

Also check `.config/autostart`, everything from this directory should be started automatically. Pre-plasma startup scripts are stored in `.config/plasma-workspace/env`.

If you have enabled previous session restoring (in System Settings → Startup and Shutdown → Desktop Session) its config is saved in `~/.config/ksmserverrc`

Comment: This is where things *should* be, not where things *are* listed/manageable from. For instance, it doesn't list "kaccess" even though it starts automatically. The GUI bum may list some more programs which are started automatically.

Comment: Thank you. It was the session restoring starting those programs. Why always those two that I never use? that is another question. Fortunately, they don't start any more.